# Double.NaN is an object

Tags: java

```
public class Double1 {    

    public static double parseDouble(String _s, double _def) {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(_s);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return _def;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double1 db=new Double1();
        boolean ab=db.parseDouble("vijay", Double.NaN)!=Double.NaN?true:false;
        System.out.println("ab value: "+ ab);
        System.out.println(Double.NaN==Double.NaN);
    }
}
```

It should return `true` where as the above code returns `false`. Why?

Comment: Writing `condition ? true : false` is plain silly if you think about it. Just say `condition`.

Comment: ...as is calling a static method on an instance (use `Double1.parseDouble(...)` and don't create an instance of it). And put `parseDouble` final `return` in the `catch` block which should be more specific with which exceptions in catches (NPE??).

Answer (score 14):

NaN's compare false to everything - including themselves.

You can check for NaN with

```
Double.isNaN(doubleValue)
```

Which actually does nothing other than using exactly this behavior: A value x is a NaN if `x != x`.

Comment: Could you add something about how one would check for NaN-ness?

Comment: (Because of ANSI/IEEE 754-1985.)

Comment: @KerrekSB [Double#isNan()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28%29)

Comment: It's like saying infinity == infinity, i.e. 1/0 == 2/0, which is just silly.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk: Not in the least. Infinity *does* compare equal to itself. It's actually a well-defined point on a suitably extended real line.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, mathematically, please tell me you're pulling my leg.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk: Not in the least. Think about infinity as a limit. `lim_{x \to 0+ }(1/x)` is the same as `lim_{x \to 0+}(2/x)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Sorry I agree with @JacoVanNiekerk. Simple mathematical explanation: if `infinity == infinity` then `infinity - infinity == 0` then `infinity - infinity + 1 == 0 + 1` then `infinity - infinity == 1`. Therefore comparing infinity with infinity is silly.

Comment: (If you don't mind abandoning signedness, you can dispose of the sign and just get a single infinity; that would be [RP^1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line). That's not so useful for computations, though.)

Comment: public class Double1 {
 
 public static double parseDouble(String _s, double _def) {
  try {
   return Double.parseDouble(_s);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
  }
  return _def;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Double1 db=new Double1();
  boolean ab=db.parseDouble("vijay", Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)!=Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY?true:false;
   System.out.println("ab value: "+ab);
   
 }

}  If we can't compare  NaN, how does the other Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY is compared and returns the expected value false.

Comment: @Max In IEEE754 terms you can actually compare infinity to infinity and will get the "correct" result. But subtracting infinity from infinity results in NaN so everything's fine.

Comment: ok, I have a string value, parsing it to double will give me  a double value or defalut value. 
Basing on the return value I can determine it  is  double or not. 
if(db.parseDouble("vijay", Double.NaN)!=Double.NaN) 
  //wirte it as number....
else 
//wirte it as string  ...

Comment: @GrailsDev That part is actually not that hard, consider that `infinity + 1 == infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

but it's normal. Your parseDouble method tries to parse "vijay" and returns _def because "vijay" is not a double value.And `db.parseDouble("vijay", Double.NaN)` will return `Double.NaN` an finally `Double.NaN!=Double.NaN` is false.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the first print statement returns true and second one returns false.